# What are the differences between different versions of the original Oregon Trail?

Tags: version-differences, the-oregon-trail

From Wikipedia, we can see that there are at least 3 versions of the original Oregon Trail:

1. The Oregon Trail
2. The Oregon Trail 1.2
3. The Oregon Trail Deluxe

What are the differences between the different versions?  Are they simply the same game with better graphics, or do they differ in the game options/mechanics?

Comment: Not a full answer, and probably way more in-depth than your question is looking for, but there were at least technically three versions before the Apple II "Oregon Trail" you're starting with. Give [this](https://www.filfre.net/2011/04/on-the-trail-of-the-oregon-trail-part-4/) and [this](https://www.filfre.net/2011/04/on-the-trail-of-the-oregon-trail-part-5/) a look for the specifics, and then cycle back to the first three parts if you want the whole story.